# Why is my mail blocked by Gmail (Marked as spam)

Tags: centos, email, spam-marked, transip

Three days ago I have installed CentOS with Directadmin what I've received from TransIP. The mailserver is now working, configured DKIM, SPF, DMARC etc.

There is only one problem... mailproviders like Gmail and Hotmail are still blocking my mails.

I just did a port25.com Authentication and they giving me the following information:

```
   This message is an automatic response from Port25's authentication verifier service at verifier.port25.com.  The service allows email senders to perform a simple check of various sender authentication mechanisms.  It is provided free of charge, in the hope that it is useful to the email community.  While it is not officially supported, we welcome any feedback you may have at <verifier-feedback@port25.com>.

Thank you for using the verifier,

The Port25 Solutions, Inc. team

==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname:  server.cyberdonky.net
Source IP:      37.97.186.120
mail-from:      youri@cyberdonky.net

----------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass 
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=youri@cyberdonky.net
DNS record(s):
    cyberdonky.net. SPF (no records)
    cyberdonky.net. 3600 IN TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=none; rua=mailto:spam@cyberdonky.net"
    cyberdonky.net. 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtEK1VZVoXjzK8sR+8RKz+ZX1YKAdKgt0wM0E58McM0OQsjLrk2+B8A0zcNxexTphGmLG2byLSqeCyqESX4P1FqNYGwJXEhBYkhm03QckOIi0CfSyJ9Y77ZklWEjUnQ1QNdpaR3HK/gRKyO3qoFxIJuUDX7A2gvABRXs1LY6ntwbVK/UQgBuzCXdfd6+JhybJf+Ja17NzPmaKTlnNBRXiLjpUH94puTU25UC2YnDn/MnUBc/v3CEnfozpRLUe39o2NVgE7zEriUVb6cnCxKEfDFlDY1DDqfAhg7Bkq4tc2/4YSU2N/BFlwSO22LvKzZAK6DP0gafjHwboEMVcvS1vFQIDAQAB"
    cyberdonky.net. 60 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:37.97.186.120 ip6:2a01:7c8:aac1:218::1/64 ~all"
    cyberdonky.net. 3600 IN A 37.97.186.120

----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=youri@cyberdonky.net DNS record(s):

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass (matches From: youri@cyberdonky.net)
ID(s) verified: header.d=cyberdonky.net
Canonicalized Headers:
    content-type:multipart/alternative;'20'boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0028_01D1AB92.769116D0"'0D''0A'
    mime-version:1.0'0D''0A'
    message-id:<002701d1ab81$b3073560$1915a020$@cyberdonky.net>'0D''0A'
    date:Wed,'20'11'20'May'20'2016'20'14:36:10'20'+0200'0D''0A'
    subject:Test'0D''0A'
    to:<check-auth2@verifier.port25.com>'0D''0A'
    from:"CyberDonky'20'|'20'Youri"'20'<youri@cyberdonky.net>'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'q=dns/txt;'20'c=relaxed/relaxed;'20'd=cyberdonky.net;'20's=x;'20'h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Date:Subject:To:From;'20'bh=s37mJd+u1gZCpTcbPXNl9H/EUriDfQd/kS956rC9gJw=;'20'b=;

Canonicalized Body:
    This'20'is'20'a'20'multipart'20'message'20'in'20'MIME'20'format.'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    ------=_NextPart_000_0028_01D1AB92.769116D0'0D''0A'
    Content-Type:'20'text/plain;'0D''0A'
    '20'charset="us-ascii"'0D''0A'
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:'20'7bit'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    Even'20'testen'20'of'20'dit'20'werkt.'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    123'20'Port'20'25.'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    Check!'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    ------=_NextPart_000_0028_01D1AB92.769116D0'0D''0A'
    Content-Type:'20'text/html;'0D''0A'
    '20'charset="us-ascii"'0D''0A'
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:'20'quoted-printable'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    <html'20'xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"'20'='0D''0A'
    xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"'20'='0D''0A'
    xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"'20'='0D''0A'
    xmlns:m=3D"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"'20'='0D''0A'
    xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META'20'='0D''0A'
    HTTP-EQUIV=3D"Content-Type"'20'CONTENT=3D"text/html;'20'='0D''0A'
    charset=3Dus-ascii"><meta'20'name=3DGenerator'20'content=3D"Microsoft'20'Word'20'14'20'='0D''0A'
    (filtered'20'medium)"><style><!--'0D''0A'
    /*'20'Font'20'Definitions'20'*/'0D''0A'
    @font-face'0D''0A'
    '20'{font-family:"Cambria'20'Math";'0D''0A'
    '20'panose-1:2'20'4'20'5'20'3'20'5'20'4'20'6'20'3'20'2'20'4;}'0D''0A'
    @font-face'0D''0A'
    '20'{font-family:Calibri;'0D''0A'
    '20'panose-1:2'20'15'20'5'20'2'20'2'20'2'20'4'20'3'20'2'20'4;}'0D''0A'
    /*'20'Style'20'Definitions'20'*/'0D''0A'
    p.MsoNormal,'20'li.MsoNormal,'20'div.MsoNormal'0D''0A'
    '20'{margin:0cm;'0D''0A'
    '20'margin-bottom:.0001pt;'0D''0A'
    '20'font-size:11.0pt;'0D''0A'
    '20'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";'0D''0A'
    '20'mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}'0D''0A'
    a:link,'20'span.MsoHyperlink'0D''0A'
    '20'{mso-style-priority:99;'0D''0A'
    '20'color:blue;'0D''0A'
    '20'text-decoration:underline;}'0D''0A'
    a:visited,'20'span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed'0D''0A'
    '20'{mso-style-priority:99;'0D''0A'
    '20'color:purple;'0D''0A'
    '20'text-decoration:underline;}'0D''0A'
    span.E-mailStijl17'0D''0A'
    '20'{mso-style-type:personal-compose;'0D''0A'
    '20'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";'0D''0A'
    '20'color:windowtext;}'0D''0A'
    .MsoChpDefault'0D''0A'
    '20'{mso-style-type:export-only;'0D''0A'
    '20'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";'0D''0A'
    '20'mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}'0D''0A'
    @page'20'WordSection1'0D''0A'
    '20'{size:612.0pt'20'792.0pt;'0D''0A'
    '20'margin:70.85pt'20'70.85pt'20'70.85pt'20'70.85pt;}'0D''0A'
    div.WordSection1'0D''0A'
    '20'{page:WordSection1;}'0D''0A'
    --></style><!--[if'20'gte'20'mso'20'9]><xml>'0D''0A'
    <o:shapedefaults'20'v:ext=3D"edit"'20'spidmax=3D"1026"'20'/>'0D''0A'
    </xml><![endif]--><!--[if'20'gte'20'mso'20'9]><xml>'0D''0A'
    <o:shapelayout'20'v:ext=3D"edit">'0D''0A'
    <o:idmap'20'v:ext=3D"edit"'20'data=3D"1"'20'/>'0D''0A'
    </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body'20'lang=3DNL'20'link=3Dblue'20'='0D''0A'
    vlink=3Dpurple><div'20'class=3DWordSection1><p'20'class=3DMsoNormal>Even'20'='0D''0A'
    testen'20'of'20'dit'20'werkt.<o:p></o:p></p><p'20'class=3DMsoNormal>123'20'Port'20'25.'20'='0D''0A'
    <o:p></o:p></p><p'20'class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p'20'='0D''0A'
    class=3DMsoNormal>Check!<o:p></o:p></p><p'20'='0D''0A'
    class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p'20'='0D''0A'
    class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p'20'='0D''0A'
    class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p'20'='0D''0A'
    class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>'0D''0A'
    ------=_NextPart_000_0028_01D1AB92.769116D0--'0D''0A'


DNS record(s):
    x._domainkey.cyberdonky.net. 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtEK1VZVoXjzK8sR+8RKz+ZX1YKAdKgt0wM0E58McM0OQsjLrk2+B8A0zcNxexTphGmLG2byLSqeCyqESX4P1FqNYGwJXEhBYkhm03QckOIi0CfSyJ9Y77ZklWEjUnQ1QNdpaR3HK/gRKyO3qoFxIJuUDX7A2gvABRXs1LY6ntwbVK/UQgBuzCXdfd6+JhybJf+Ja17NzPmaKTlnNBRXiLjpUH94puTU25UC2YnDn/MnUBc/v3CEnfozpRLUe39o2NVgE7zEriUVb6cnCxKEfDFlDY1DDqfAhg7Bkq4tc2/4YSU2N/BFlwSO22LvKzZAK6DP0gafjHwboEMVcvS1vFQIDAQAB"

Public key used for verification: x._domainkey.cyberdonky.net (2048 bits)

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs (RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.

----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass 
ID(s) verified: header.From=youri@cyberdonky.net DNS record(s):
    cyberdonky.net. SPF (no records)
    cyberdonky.net. 3600 IN TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=none; rua=mailto:spam@cyberdonky.net"
    cyberdonky.net. 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtEK1VZVoXjzK8sR+8RKz+ZX1YKAdKgt0wM0E58McM0OQsjLrk2+B8A0zcNxexTphGmLG2byLSqeCyqESX4P1FqNYGwJXEhBYkhm03QckOIi0CfSyJ9Y77ZklWEjUnQ1QNdpaR3HK/gRKyO3qoFxIJuUDX7A2gvABRXs1LY6ntwbVK/UQgBuzCXdfd6+JhybJf+Ja17NzPmaKTlnNBRXiLjpUH94puTU25UC2YnDn/MnUBc/v3CEnfozpRLUe39o2NVgE7zEriUVb6cnCxKEfDFlDY1DDqfAhg7Bkq4tc2/4YSU2N/BFlwSO22LvKzZAK6DP0gafjHwboEMVcvS1vFQIDAQAB"
    cyberdonky.net. 60 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:37.97.186.120 ip6:2a01:7c8:aac1:218::1/64 ~all"
    cyberdonky.net. 3600 IN A 37.97.186.120

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin v3.4.0 (2014-02-07)

Result:         ham  (-3.4 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
-1.4 RP_MATCHES_RCVD        Envelope sender domain matches handover relay domain
-1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                            [score: 0.0000]
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                            domain
 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
```

I have no idea what the problem is and how I can fix that Gmail/Hotmail etc. receiving my mails.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Youri

Comment: Gmail tells you exactly why they put a message in Spam, when you open the message.

Comment: If you just updated your SPF record, you may have to wait for DNS to update on Gmail before it passes the spam check.

Answer (score 1):

Google,Hotmail,Yahoo have their own spam consideration policy. If you have correctly setup the SPF,DKIM,DMARC and you have fixed the outgoing spam problem, your IP/domain should be released automatically.

You can report problem with bounce back email to Google Team here :- 
https://support.google.com/mail/contact/msgdelivery

Same for Hotmail, you can submit details from here :-
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&ccsid=635989043182465986